# UI5 Grid Table Drag & Drop what is rank?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am new in the UI5 thing and got some questions..

i want to implement the Grid Table with [Drag and Drop Ui5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.DnD/code/Controller.controller.js).

but I cant really figure out how.. i mean the most of it i understand but what is with the rank? also in the controller

```
<Table
    id="table1"
    selectionMode="Single"
    rows="{
        path: '/ProductCollection',
        filters: {path: 'Rank', operator: 'EQ', value1: '0'}
    }"
```

I downloaded it and looked for the Rank path but even in the product.json model is no Rank..

maybe someone can help me to implement it with odata service.

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

Rank is a product property which they calculate at runtime, see Controller.controller.js line 46. So, they load **product.json** and then copy **config.initialRank** to product Rank:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. yeah i figured it out.. and looked up in the model.. Problem is first of all it only adds 0 as Rank dont go up or something and second.. i can drag or drop. and there is no error message..